# compare file-based systems and a relational database

Tags: database-design

I don't know the exact difference of both can you please compare file-based systems and a 
relational database?

Answer (score 1):

A full answer to this would be huge.  Off the top of my head, some of the things a RDBMS will give you are

- role-based security
- transactions
- consistent backups across multiple files
- declarative referential integrity - primary keys, foreign keys, constraints etc.
- a standard declarative programming language (SQL)
- new implementation algorithms can be deployed independently of the client application e.g. an improved sort algorithm
- an optimizer to decide which access strategy will be cost-effective for each query
- journaling; point in time recovery (though such file systems do exist)
- embedded programming and activation with triggers and stored procedures

.. amongst many, many others.

Comment: Independence of the physical storage _location_. Independence of the physical storage _structure_